# Is there a way to get first and last row in postgresql COPY command?

Tags: postgresql, time-series, timescaledb

I want to read from a CSV file a number of rows every few minutes, is there a way to keep track of what row it was inserted last time, and start the next insertion from that specific row?
In SQL Server I know it is possible using the bulk insert command, but I don't know how I could do it in postgresql.
I tried using COPY command and timescaledb-parallel-copy command but in the latter one i could only limit the number of rows I want to insert.
I am trying to do this to compare the performance of bulk inserting over time between SQL Server and a time-series database

`timescaledb-parallel-copy --db-name test --table 'test_table' --file weather_big_conditions.csv --connection "host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres sslmode=disable" -limit 2000000`

Comment: This is going to need more information 1) Is the CSV regenerated between the times you read it? 2) Are the rows in the CSV file in a stable order? 3) Is there a unique id in the file or the table it is imported into? 4) Is `test_table` a staging table or the end destination table? 5) Some example data would help, can you provide?  Add answers as update to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the code [here](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy/blob/master/cmd/timescaledb-parallel-copy/main.go#L199-L206), I think it's possible to combine the `--skip-head=true` and `--header-line-count=N` which N is a number that will work as an `offset` skipping the lines that you want from the file. You can see that the code is prepared for it.

I haven't tested it but you can give it a try.